# How to make domain point to different server without downtime?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, domain-registration, linode

I have a domain name on `example.com`, which points to their shared hosted server right now. I want this to point to my Linode server.

How do I make the domain point to my Linode server without having any downtime?

Linode tells me that I just have to change the name servers there and it'll handle the rest. Is it all? I cannot afford there to be a couple of hours of downtime.

P.S. `example.com` is running PHP_Apache, Linode is running *Nodejs*. Assume that I'll have the backend on node ready to handle all requests.

Comment: Sorry but there is already a vast amount of questions and answers regarding changing host without or with minimal downtime as possible.

Comment: Sorry! I just needed to be sure. I changed the nameservers to linode's and followed the steps in [Linode's docs](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/dns/dns-manager#dns-set-up-checklist) and it was done smoothly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just change the name servers and you won't have any downtime as long as you leave the original server up. Keep in mind that changes on one server won't be reflected on the other server, so that if you have a mailling list for people to join and they join on the old server, unless you sync data it will be lost.

Also be aware that the new nameserver will propagate for different people at different times. The generic advice is to allow up to 72 hours for complete propagation, though in reality 4 - 6 hours is the norm.

Sometimes people may jump back to seeing the old server...it can be a little weird.  If you want to monitor propagation check out http://www.whatsmydns.net/ and choose NS from the dropdown.

P.S. Your PS about what is running on the server is completely irrelevant.